# How to do a filter for ngFor in angular2 that passes 5 values into it?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

How to do a filter for ngFor in angular2 that passes 4 values into it?

**This is where I current am with the filter code:**

```
import { Pipe } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
    name: 'mapFilter', 
  pure: true
})

export class MapFilter {
   transform(items, [searchTerms]) { 
      return items;
  }
}
```

**This is my html**

```
  <tr *ngFor="let item of jobs | mapFilter: [searchTerm, county, region, type, markers]" class="animated fadeIn" (click)="viewJob(item)">
```

As you can see I'm trying to pass 5 values into the filter called: searchTerm, county, region, type, marker.

So I can then filter the result.

I'm not sure how to pass those into the filter. So mainly stuck on the mapFilter pipe code bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of jobs | mapFilter:searchTerm:county:region:type: markers"
     class="animated fadeIn" (click)="viewJob(item)">
```

And get them in the pipe class this way:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'mapFilter'
})
export class MapFilter {
  transform(items, searchTerms) { 
    let searchTerm = searchTerms[0];
    let county = searchTerms[1];
    (...)
    return items;
  }
}
```

Comment: how do I run your example app for the dist folder to see if the index file works? I forgot the command for git bash that you said?

Comment: You could use a static server like `http-server`. After having installed it (`npm install http-server -g`), go into the `dist` folder and type: `http-server . -c-1`...

Comment: could you take a look at this build question for me for angular2:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37525356/how-to-create-an-angular-2-build-folder-when-using-systemjs-config-js

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working. Looks like they've changed the pipe. it now needs to look like this transform(items, searchTerm1, searchTerm2, SearchTerm3) {